# repeating a program multiple times (conducting calculations and writing the result in another file)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, repeat, calculation

I have a code for analysing large amount of data (form two different files it takes the values which are separated by a space, it then calculates the relative difference between those values and writes them in another file).

```
from itertools import islice

with open('ex_original_1.idl') as f1, open('ex_new_1.idl') as f2:
    with open('ex_dif_1.txt', 'w') as f3:
        f1 = islice(f1, 905, None)  # skip first 905 lines
        f2 = islice(f2, 905, None)  # skip first 905 lines

        for f1_line, f2_line in zip(f1, f2):
            f1_vals = map(float, f1_line.strip().split())
            f2_vals = map(float, f2_line.strip().split())
            for v1, v2 in zip(f1_vals, f2_vals):
                try:
                    result = v1/v2
                    f3.write(str(result)+"\n")
                except ZeroDivisionError:           #should there be a value of zero
                    print("Encountered a value equal to zero in the second file. Skipping...")
                    continue
```

Whilst it works well on two files (ex_original_1.idl and ex_new_1.idl), I do have a lot more files of the same type (~500). I would like to perform this program more times and the output files should be named in a logical matter: ex_dif_1.txt. To make the matters more structured, the 2 different types (ex_original_i and ex_new_i) are located in different directories and I would like to write the new files in a separate directory (If i understand correctly, before the file name I include the path for all files, yes?). To recap the files which I have are:

- ex_original_1, ex_original_2, ex_original_3 ... ex_original_500
- ex_new_1, ex_new_2, ex_new_3 ... ex_original_500

I would like to get:

- ex_dif_1, ex_dif_2, ex_dif_3 ... ex_dif_500

Using this line of code, which works only once. 
Should it be appropriate to make another separate program to run this one multiple times or rather to include a command in this existing program, an example would be appreciated?

Hope it was clear enough. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

if files are present in different folders, this will differ. Let me know the exact scenario.

If present on the same folder, you can try this.

Instead of hardcoding the filenames, get them dynamically! If that outfile isnt present, get the default name, otherwise one plus the old file.

```
>>> import os
>>> files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.lower().startswith('ex_dif_')]
>>> files
['ex_dif_1.txt']
>>> outfile="outfilefolder/ex_diff_%d.txt"
>>> number = 1
>>> if files:number=int(max(files,key=os.path.getctime).split('_')[2].split('.')[0])+1
>>> outfile=outfile%(number) if files else outfile%1`
>>> print outfile
'ex_diff_2.txt'
```

Similarly for ex_orignal and ex_new input file.

```
>>> ofile="ofilefolder/ex_original_%d.idl"
>>> ofile1=ofile%(number) if files else ofile%1`
>>> nfile="nfilefolder/ex_new_%d.idl"
>>> nfile=nfile%(number) if files else nfile%1`
```

Change the part where you open the file to get the dynamically generated names.

```
with open(ofile) as f1, open(filen) as f2:
    with open(outfile, 'w') as f3:
```

Comment: yes, the fils are located in different folders. ex_original_i and ex_new_i are located in separate folders. And I would like to calculate the differences into another folder.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it there. I have written it as you suggested (I hope correctly). It gives out an error: max() arg is an empty sequence.

Should I ask another question and post the whole written code?

Comment: Not necessary! I've added the edit. This error will occur where there is not file in output folder. That is, when `files` is an empty list!

Answer (score 0):

Start your program with a loop. Guess this should work for you...

```
list_of_files = os.listdir("path to files")
in1files = [file for file in list_of_files if file.startswith('ex_original_')]
in2files = [file for file in list_of_files if file.startswith('ex_new_')]
outfiles=[]
for i in range(0,len(in1files)):
    outfile = "ex_dif_"+str(i+1)
    file1 = in1files[i]
    file2 = in2files[i]
    with open(file1,'r') as f1, open(file2,'r') as f2:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as f3:
            {your stuff continues here on....}
```

Comment: Close the files when you are done. If files are in different directories then simply assign the value to the lists using os.listdir("path") method. I have not run this before posting so let me know in case you face any error...

Comment: When you open a file [`with` statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) you need not explicitly close them!

Comment: I did not know of that.. Thanks for the info ;)